# Google Play Store states "You will have 90 days to release your app to production after starting Pre-Registration". What happens then?

Tags: android, google-play

This question was already asked a long time ago but there were no great answers.

Does anybody have experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: You release it after 90 days...

Comment: Well and if it's not ready by the time the 90th day comes? I would just like to be able to present in in the play store already altough there is much work left to do. 90 Days feels too short to me